# Scaled Bitmap is failed in Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: java, android, bitmap, null, scale

Thanks for earlier support.
Currently I am working on a Project where i need to resize images downloaded from Server. Images have a large resolution so i want to resize as per screenSize of Device. Here below is my code. Please have a look.

```
                    // decode image size initially
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
        stream1.close();

        // Find the correct scale value.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
        stream2.close();
```

But once i get the desirable scale it finds a null-bitmap at the end of the Code in case of Samsung Galaxy S3. It's working fine on Emulator, Samsung galaxy S4, Htc one v. I am also worried about generalization of the Code so it should be working on Every device.

If anybody had experience for such a Problem Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

what's your REQUIRED_SIZE value? set it 1024. Because may be that was due to Out of memory exception while decode large resolution image.

Comment: It's 720 in case of Samsung galaxy S3.